# Failed to read pipelines yaml file

Tags: logstash, pipeline

Here is my issue concerning the pipelines.yml file. Firstly, i am using Elasticsearch 6.6 with Logstash 6.2.2. Both are installed in a VM into my own Google Cloud account (not this that ELK provides, but just in my own hosting in my GCP account). There i have 3 folders where log files from IoT devices come and just want to injest them simultaneusly in 3 corresponding indexes, so i 've made a pipelines.yml file inside the logstash/config path, with the following content:

```
-pipeline.id: pipeline1
 path.config: "/config/p1/logstash-learning.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
-pipeline.id: pipeline2
 path.config: "/config/p2/logstash-groundtruth.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
-pipeline.id: pipeline3
 path.config: "/config/p3/logstash-fieldtest.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
```

So, when i run logstash with the command ./bin/logstash (with this command we tell Logstash to load the default file pipelines.yml, right?), i take the error message below and i cannot figure out why this happens. Note that pipelines.yml has full permission of accesibility.

```
jruby: warning: unknown property jruby.regexp.interruptible
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-12-17T16:36:43,877][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2019-12-17T16:36:43,933][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
ERROR: Failed to read pipelines yaml file. Location: /home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/config/pipelines.yml
usage:
  bin/logstash -f CONFIG_PATH [-t] [-r] [] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash --modules MODULE_NAME [-M "MODULE_NAME.var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE"] [-t] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash -e CONFIG_STR [-t] [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
  bin/logstash -i SHELL [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
  bin/logstash -V [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
  bin/logstash --help
[2019-12-17T16:36:45,347][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit
```

Comment: How are you starting logstash? Do you have a directory named `/config` in the root of your filesystem with your pipelines config or your configs are in the directory `/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/config/` ?

Comment: My logstash is in the path: /home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/bin and the 3 configs files (pipelines) are in the path:/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/config in three respective subfolders there: /b1, /b2, /b3.

Comment: make a seperate folder outside the config path: /home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/folderName and move all the three conf  files in this folder.

Comment: @Angel H, I made a separate folder outside the config path in the: /home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/pipelines and move all the three conf files in this folder, but the same error persists whenever i call logstash with the command: ./bin/logstash.   It seems to me (according to error message i get) that logstash finds successfully the pipelines.yml file but fails to open it and i don't know why. The permissions for this file are the following. Is something wrong with it? Do i have to do something with logstash.yml also?   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root      root       402 Dec 18 09:39 pipelines.yml*

Answer (score 5):

Finally, with the use of http://www.yamllint.com/ online yaml tester that the right syntax of the pipelines.yml was the following:

```
-
pipeline.id: pipeline1
 path.config: "/config/p1/logstash-learning.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1

-
pipeline.id: pipeline2
 path.config: "/config/p2/logstash-groundtruth.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1

-
pipeline.id: pipeline3
 path.config: "/config/p3/logstash-fieldtest.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the path in path.config?,

```
-pipeline.id: pipeline1
 path.config: "/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/pipelines/logstash-learning.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
-pipeline.id: pipeline2
 path.config: "/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/pipelines/logstash-groundtruth.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
-pipeline.id: pipeline3
 path.config: "/home/evangelos/logstash-6.2.2/pipelines/logstash-fieldtest.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
```

After setting this above in pipelines.yml file,
Run the below command to run the pipelines,

```
bin/logstash --path.settings config/
```

Comment: Yes, i made the change you said in path.config, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep space line between each pipeline as below.

```
-pipeline.id: pipeline1
 path.config: "/config/p1/logstash-learning.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1

-pipeline.id: pipeline2
 path.config: "/config/p2/logstash-groundtruth.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1

-pipeline.id: pipeline3
 path.config: "/config/p3/logstash-fieldtest.conf"
 pipeline.workers: 1
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing changes. I still receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the quotation marks in path.config worked for me:

```
-pipeline.id: pipeline1
 path.config: /config/p1/logstash-learning.conf
 pipeline.workers: 1

-pipeline.id: pipeline2
 path.config: /config/p2/logstash-groundtruth.conf
 pipeline.workers: 1

-pipeline.id: pipeline3
 path.config: /config/p3/logstash-fieldtest.conf
 pipeline.workers: 1
```